# Dieterici's Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Dieterici's Equation of state for a gas is given by

$P(V-b)e^{a/RVT}=RT$

where $a$, $b$, and $R$ are constants. When treating $V$ as a function of $R$ and $T$, show that

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}=(R+\frac{a}{TV})/(\frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{V^2})$.

---

I tried defining $F=P(V-b)e^{a/RVT}-RT=F(t(T,P),p(T,P),V(T,P))=0$ where $t=T$ and $p=P$. From here I attempted the chain rule, getting

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial T}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}$

$= \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}=0$

I stopped here because I honestly did not know if I'm even on track, and I felt lost. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find
$$F_T=P(V-b)\left(\dfrac{-a}{RVT^2}\right)e^{\frac{a}{RVT}}-R$$
and
$$F_V=Pe^{\frac{a}{RVT}}+P(V-b)\left(\dfrac{-a}{RTV^2}\right)e^{\frac{a}{RVT}}$$
and use
$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial T}=-\dfrac{F_T}{F_V}$$
then simplify!

Answer (score 1):

You are quite not on the right track. Write the equation as: $F(P,V,T) =0$, then use the F function to find $\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$. This calculation is standard at the level of 1st year college calculus.

Comment: I really do not understand why you had a downvote for the correct solution. Then $\to +1$

Comment: I appreciate your helpful answer, but I think you should be careful of comments like "This is standard 1st year calculus," because people could take that as somewhat condescending. Also, I don't believe I was totally off the mark with my original attempt. Substituting T for t and P for p in my last equation, I get ∂F/∂T+(∂F/∂P)(∂P/∂T)+(∂F/∂V)(∂V/∂T)=0. Holding P constant,  I have ∂F/∂T+(∂F/∂V)(∂V/∂T)=0. From this, I got ∂V/∂T=(-∂F/∂T)/(∂F/∂V).